# Logout USER form backoffice after 30 minutes of inactivity

Tags: wp-admin, users, user-roles, security, session

I looking for to logout user from backoffice after 30 minutes of non activity except Administrator role.

Thanks.

Comment: WP doesn't use PHP sessions, I suspect there's some missing knowledge here about how cookies work, you can give it an expiration time but not a TTL/timeout

Comment: It helps when you take the time to do a search. And although you seem not understand the rules of SE (therefore my down vote!), here a [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/inactive-logout/)

Comment: inactive logout plugin does not work well. I tested it before put my question here.... but thanks for your reply